# Importing functions from other file is not working for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a file "functionsList.py" with a series of functions.

I am trying to import them into another file in the same file path like the following:

```
from functionsList import function1, function2 (etc.)
```

However I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named functionsList

Why is it looking for a module from the library (presumably) rather than reading my file? From other examples it looks  pretty straightforward but I can't get it to work at all. I have the `sys` module already imported in case that makes any difference.

Comment: If you have imported `sys`, add `print(sys.path)` before `from functionsList import ...`. It outputs a list of directories. Is the file `functionsList.py` in one of those directories? If not, that's why it can't be imported.

Comment: yes they are in the same path. using ```import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path().resolve())``` on the original file the path is "C:\Users\Cian\Desktop\Project" but when I use ```sys.path``` the path is C:\\Users\\Cian\\Desktop\\Project. maybe the double '\' throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

**File structure**

```
$ tree
.
└── my_app
    ├── functionsList.py
    └─── main.py
```

**functionsList.py**

```
def function1():
    print("function1 called")
```

### Solution 1:

Use [explicit relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) which are relative to the importing file explicitly indicated via `.` (same folder) or `..` (parent folder) or more. Note that the usage of [implicit relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) has already been removed in Python3

> Implicit relative imports should *never* be used and have been removed in Python 3.

**main.py**

```
from .functionsList import function1  # Notice the trailing dot (.)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("main called")
    function1()
```

### Solution 2:

Use absolute imports. In this case, we can assume that the root folder is `my_app` and the package would either be executed from that root folder or at least would be included in the `sys.path` (manually or via the flag `PYTHONPATH`).

**main.py**

```
from my_app.functionsList import function1
...
```

### Solution 3:

Add the directory containing the imported file `functionsList.py` to the `sys.path`.

**main.py**

```
from functionsList import function1
...
```

**Terminal**

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/my_app
```

**Output for the solutions above:**

```
$ python3 -m my_app.main
main called
function1 called
```

Comment: thanks. Solution1 is not working for me, getting an error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". Sol2 is what i was trying to do. i tried typing the above in the terminal but get an error from the $ character.What should the "my_app" be in this context? the folder where the files are saved?

Comment: Soln 1 should work if you execute your app as a module `python3 -m the_app.someFile` instead of a standalone script `python3 the_app/someFile.py`. For the terminal command, you have to set the root of your app, so if your script is in `/home/me/Documents/my_proj/the_app_1/files/functions/functionsList.py` and `/home/me/Documents/my_proj/the_app_1/files/functions/someFile.py`, then type `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/me/Documents` and then write the imports as `from my_proj.the_app_1.files.functions.functionsList import function1`.